# Textmate's Filter Through Command

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew, textmate

I run anything there on document or selection I get

> /bin/sh: pandoc: command not found

[image]

I installed pandoc by `brew install pandoc` 
My pandoc's version is 1.13.2.1.

There is probably something broken in my $PATH. 
Echo $PATH gives `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin`.

Both my $HOME/.profile and $HOME/.bashrc have `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` only. 
Doing `ls -1 /bin/sh` gives `/bin/sh` so existing.

Why does this error message come?

Comment: It's `pandoc` which is not found, not `sh`. What does `type padoc` return in Terminal?

Comment: I get `type pandoc pandoc is hashed (/usr/local/bin/pandoc)` from `type pandoc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution here. 
Click the box in settings for $PATH

[image]